# File Not Found instead Display error NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Hi I have problem when i Log in first time on website on page with edit password is, File Not Found

If i try first edit password and sended form at the same time add code to template

```
           <% if(error.old.length >= 1) { %>
               <%= error.old %>
               <% } %>
```

and refresh, all is ok, error is display, after refresh all is ok, but first must be sended form, how to fix it??

NodeJS:

```
if(_.isEmpty(req.body.new) || req.body.new.length >= 5 || req.body.new != req.body.newConfirm) {
  errors.new = 'Nowe hasło jest nieprawidłowe!'
}
 if(isMatch == false) {
   errors.old = 'Stare hasło jest nieprawidłowe!'
}  

 if(errors) {
    res.render('user/user/profile', { error : errors })
  } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
<% if(error.old && error.old.length >= 1) { %>
    <%= error.old %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Working, Question, How to properly validate in NodeJS, by Regexp?? or Lodash?? If I have form with address -> firstname, surname, city, country, phone

Comment: If you asking for code quality and best approach, please post this question in codereview stackechange. If you want to test your request body, please validator component in it, thanks.